# How do I find all conjugates of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: field-theory

> How do I find all conjugates of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

I have shown that $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$ is a root of $X^4 - 2X^2 - 1$ and this polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, hence there are at most 4 conjugates of $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$.

How do I proceed to find all the conjugates?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to see the result is as follows: You found the irreducible polynomial for $\alpha=\sqrt{1+\sqrt 2}$ essentially by noticing that if you square $\alpha$, then subtract $1$, you obtain a a number that, when squared, gives $2$: $f(X)=(X^2-1)^2-2=X^4-2X^2-1$. But it is of course the case for *all* roots of $f$ that squaring, subtracting $1$, and squaring again  yields $2$. Hence clearly the four sign choices in $\pm\sqrt{1\pm\sqrt 2}$ give you the four roots of $f$.

Comment: Very clearly expressed!

Comment: @Hagen Would you check my comment on Rolf's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Note that finding the conjugates of your given root is equivalent to factoring the minimal polynomial into linear terms $(X-\alpha_1)(X-\alpha_2)(X-\alpha_3)(X-\alpha_4)$.

Using the quadratic formula, you can rewrite your minimal polynomial as $(X^2-1-\sqrt{2})(X^2-1+\sqrt{2})$, which is then easy to factor into linear terms.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this by using conjugation isomorphism? It's written in my text that " since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$, it can be checked that $±\sqrt{1±\sqrt{2}}$ are the conjugates". I have no idea why $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$ implies this..

Comment: The Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})/\Bbb Q$ acts on the intermediate field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ (only fixing elements of $\Bbb Q$), and it therefore sends $\sqrt{2}$ to $-\sqrt{2}$.  Such an action would necessarily send a square root of $1 + \sqrt{2}$ to a square root of $1-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Why such an action would nexessarily send a **square root** of that to that??